# How do you insert row numbers into ajax functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function getvalues(){
var sendid = $('#id').val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ready.php",
data: {sendid}
}).done(function( result ) {
$("#msg").html( "worked" );
});
```

It works fine with the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="$id">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getvalues();">
```

The issue is I have multiple rows using the same function and need to differentiate them, so I use rows. What I'm asking is how do I call 1 function using 10 different rows (with 10 different IDs) without creating 10 different functions.

For example, I have a list of forms that read:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getvalues1();">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getvalues2();">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getvalues3();">
```

How do I make the function separate these without creating multiple functions?

Comment: Are the hidden and button inputs in different forms or is the id always the same?

Comment: what exactly do you want to change to the function?

Comment: They are in different forms, each has a unique ID. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: The function works fine, I have several forms with different IDs that use the same function. I need the function to recognize which ID is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pass a parameter to your function?

```
function getvalues(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ready.php",
        data: {id: id}, // I used this notation because POST request needs key-value pair to retrieve data
        success: function(result) {
            $("#msg").html("worked");
        }
    });
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="1234">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getvalues(this.form.id.value);">
```

**Note:** Ids must be unique, you can't have multiple `submit` inputs with the same ID!

Comment: Thanks this is what I need..duh I know. I forgot simple things, I'm not a javascript person so the simplest things fly over my head sometimes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yep I know, don't worry, I was just curious to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have several inputs with the same ID.  This is not allowed.  You should give each one a unique ID.

Secondly, the onclick handler will be passed an event object as a parameter.  You can retrieve the element that was clicked by using 'event.target'.  IE uses 'event.srcElement'.  Either way, once you retrieve the element, you can query for the 'id' attribute and that will identify the 'row' you are interested in.

edit:

```
<input type="button" id="submit1" value="submit" onClick="getvalues();">
<input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit" onClick="getvalues();">

function getvalues(event) {
    var id= event.target.id;  // now the id var contains "submit1", "submit2", etc.
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I've done, I gave each input a unique ID. How do I pull the unique ID with the function?